# ¿Cómo inicializar Variables en angular?

Tags: angular, excel, variables, servicio, frontend

Soy novato en angular. Estoy intentando implementar un servicio de generación de excel con otros servicios que consultan datos al backend. El problema está en que la primera vez que lanzo el proceso no funciona porque las variables no están inicializadas, la segunda vez que lanzo el proceso, se lanza con los datos que se consultaron la anterior vez.

```
<form [formGroup]="formData" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formData.value)">

  <select id="selectMunicipios" formControlName="municipios">
    <option [ngValue]="municipio" *ngFor="let municipio of municipiosSinAlta" >{{municipio.nombre}}</option>
  </select>

  <select formControlName="horarios">
    <option [ngValue]="horario" *ngFor="let horario of horariosDisponibles">{{horario.tipo}}</option>
  </select>

  <button id="btnEntrar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>

</form>
```

```
async onSubmit(formData) {
    
    this.generarExcel.GenerarExcelSimple(formData.horarios,
                                        formData.municipios);
  }
```

```
constructor(private municipios: MunicipiosService,
    private TiendasService: TiendaService,
    private GuardiasService: GuardiasService,
    private fileSaverService: FileSaverService
  ) {

  }
async GenerarExcelSimple(horario: Horario, municipio: Municipio): Promise<void> {

    this._Workbook = new Workbook();;
    this.GuardiasService.GetGuardias(municipio, horario)
      .subscribe((guardiasDias) => (this.GuardiasDias = guardiasDias));

    const sheet = this._Workbook.addWorksheet(municipio.nombre + '_' + horario.tipo);
this._Workbook.xlsx
      .writeBuffer()
      .then((data) => {
        const blob = new Blob([data]);
        this.fileSaverService.save(blob, this.fileName)
        console.log('file created');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
```

```
export class GuardiasService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) { }

  GetGuardias(municipio: Municipio, horario: Horario): Observable<GuardiasDias[]> {
    var url = GlobalConstants.apiURL + 'guardias/guardiasdias/' + municipio.id + "/" + horario.id;
    return this.http.get<GuardiasDias[]>(url)
  }
}
```

El error que sale es el siguiente

> core.mjs:7640 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot >read properties of undefined (reading '0')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
> at GenerarExcelService.createMunicipiosTable (generar->excel.service.ts:93:13)

Comment: El error parece estar en el método `GenerarExcelService.createMunicipiosTable`, cuyo código no podemos ver aquí

Comment: buenas, te lo dejo por aquí. En este caso consulta GuardiasDías e inserta los la descripción de los turnos: `private createMunicipiosTable(sheet) {
 let DayYear = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
 var DaysPerMonth = this.calculateDayMonth(i + 1);
 for (var k = 0; k < DaysPerMonth; k++) {
 var cell = this.letras[i + 1] + "" + (k + 10);
 if (this.GuardiasDias[DayYear].descripcionTurno.length <= 3) {
 sheet.getCell(cell).value = this.GuardiasDias[DayYear].descripcionTurno;
 sheet.getCell(cell).alignment = { vertical: 'center', horizontal: 'center' };
 }
 DayYear++;
 }` @PabloLozano

Comment: el problema está en que las variables del servicio quedan guardadas en caché. y cuando le vuelvo a dar al botón me exporta el excel con los datos que intenté sacar la anterior vez que pulsé en el botón. por eso la primera vez siempre da error.